# Getting error while trying to sign in with Facebook

Tags: react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using React Native Firebase Authentification and Facebook SDK for signing in. It was working completely fine but now I'm getting this error

```
[Error: [auth/configuration-not] An internal error has occurred. [ CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check project_id in you google-services.json and also in your firebase console if facebook auth in enabled or not.

[image: Please check project_id in you google-services.json and also in your firebase console if facebook auth in enabled or not.]

Comment: Checked both. downloaded google-services file and replaecd with previous one. still getting error